# Running certain scripts / commands hangs as user, OK as root

Tags: permissions, terminal

I have a user `jenkins` that is hanging when running certain scripts or commands (this is an android build server).  When running the same scripts/commands as `root`, they are executing OK.

Example:

As user `jenkins`:
`> java`
-- hangs --

As user `root`:
`> java`
-- Usage help output --

This happens for many commands run as `jenkins`, such as `android` and `java`, but commands like `ps` and `cat` work just fine.

This is a recent development so it's probably some sort of permissions issue, but I can't pin it down.

Update: Adding `set -x` to the beginning of the script reveals that it hangs when calling `java`, on this line:

`+ exec /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android-project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain assembleDebug`

The diff between running `strace -fo java` on both jenkins and root users shows a divergence at the following lines:

```
5319  stat("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.e | 5302  stat("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.e
5319  open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.e | 5302  open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.e
5319  stat("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.e | 5302  stat("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.e
5319  open("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0",  | 5302  open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
5319  stat("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe601248c0)  | 5302  fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=49448, ...}) =
5319  open("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/tls/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONL | 5302  mmap(NULL, 49448, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa
5319  stat("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/tls", 0x7ffe601248c0) = -1 EN | 5302  close(3)                          = 0
5319  open("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RD | 5302  open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
5319  stat("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe601248c0) = -1 | 5302  read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0
5319  open("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = | 5302  fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=146592, ...}) =
```

where the left side is the `jenkins` user.  It seems to be failing in an area regarding glibc-2.14, which is pointed to via environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: you can add `set -x` to the beginning of your script to get a lot more verbose output when you run it.  This may help you track down where you are running into permission issues.  (put it right below your hashbang)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  That revealed that the script is hanging when executing java.  I pasted the line above

Comment: I found this post that may be related:  https://serverfault.com/questions/220892/cannot-run-java-as-regular-linux-user

Comment: Hmm looks like that isn't it.  There are no limits enforced on users of this server

Comment: Compare the jenkins vs root execution logs when run via `strace`.  e.g. `strace -fo /tmp/jenkins-user-log /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0/bin/java -Dorg.....`

Comment: can you give us the result of `/path/to/JDK/bin/java` as user jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Some users had an environment variable set to use `glibc-2.14`, which causes java VM execution to fail.

Looking through the strace diff, there is this line in particular:

```
5319  open("/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)
```

This indicated that some users were using the `glibc-2.14` binaries, while others were using the system `glibc` libs (which are at 2.12).

The difference is that some users had the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set to the `glibc-2.14` directory and others didn't, defaulting to the system's `2.12`.  Clearing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` allowed the java command to be run successfully for these users.